Does makefile .PHONY apply to the target alias names?
Consider the Makefile below, the command clean is declared as PHONY and has an alternative name c.
Does the PHONY attribute apply also to make c or just to make clean?
.PHONY: clean

clean c:
  rm -rf *.o


Characterizing the targets of a multi-target rule as aliases of each other may sometimes be functionally accurate, but it is not semantically correct.  Thinking that way will cause trouble for you when you run into rules for which it is not functionally accurate, either (and these exist, and are not that uncommon).

Moreover, the question suggest an unhelpful higher-level view of make and makefiles.  make is not a scripting engine, and makefile rules are not functions. Artificial rules such as you ask about blur the lines a bit, but make will continually surprise you if you try to model its behavior as if makefiles were procedural programs.

GMU Make doesn't have aliases; c and clean are separate targets that execute the same recipe but that could have different prerequisites.  In this case, clean is a .PHONY prerequisite and c is not.
(It's also easy to verify this yourself by creating a file named c and seeing if make c executes the recipe.)

For rules like this, do I need ?PHONY at all (the line breaks is not shown here)?
check-all check_all ca:
python -m tox --skip-missing-interpreters false

Got it, thanks. PHONY indicates that the specific word is a command name rather than a to-be-created file name.
